How to add a new attribute to SQS message using Shoryuken before msg moves to DLQ
To add an attribute to SQS msg when an error happens, I have added a custom exception handler.
class ShoryukenExceptionHandler
  extend Shoryuken::Util

  def self.call(exception, _queue, _sqs_msg)
    puts exception.message
    byebug
    logger.error { "Processor failed: #{exception.message}" }
    logger.error { exception.backtrace.join("\n") } if exception.backtrace
    _sqs_msg.data.message_attributes["testing"]=Aws::SQS::Types::MessageAttributeValue.new({string_value: "testing string value", binary_value: nil,  string_list_values: [], binary_list_values: [], data_type: "String"})
  end

While debugging I can see the _sqs_msg being added appended with attribute "testing" but when I check it in DLQ from UI, I cannot see the attribute.
How are the messages from sqs moved to dlq? Can we add attribute to dlq msgs?
